# Rails Hide Specific Record From All Select * Type Queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, activerecord

I have a record in a table that serves as a placeholder of sorts, and doesn't represent actual data. It's bad design, I know, but I have some very awkward requirements that I have to deal with and I saw no other solutions so it's a bit of a hotfix per se.

Now lets say I have a series of SELECT *s throughout my application and I don't want to have to explicitly exclude that single record for each of them. Is there anything I can drop into my model to exclude it from all queries except for the ones where it's explicitly called? Or perhaps some logic I can put directly into my PG database?

It's the very first record in the table with an ID of 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a default scope

```
default_scope where('id != 0')
```

to your model...

In any case you want to avoid that default scope in some query, you can have `Model.unscoped...` there...

Answer (score 3):

One solution would be to define a `default_scope` that would exclude those records, see [the doc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Default/ClassMethods.html#method-i-default_scope)

So when doing `YourModel.all`, if the `default_scope` on `YourModel` excludes the correct records, you'll get what you want.

But as you said, it's bad design !

Comment: Hi pjam, this is close but not quite what I was looking for. I still need to be able to access my placeholder record, I just don't want it to appear in queries where it isn't specificially called for. With your solution it won't appear in a general `MyModel.all`, however it also produces an error if I explicitly search for it by it's ID value. Any way around that?

Answer (score 2):

Create a view excluding it:

```
create view v as
select *
from t
where id != 0
```

Now select from the view:

```
select *
from v
```